# Convert time stored as TEXT to TIME in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with the duration of a video.

I have videos from many different sources and the duration was imported into the database without being standardized. I am looking to standardize the duration here.

Consider the following table structure:

```
+-----------+
| Duration  |
+-----------+
| 5h58m38s  |
| 22m59s    |
| 05m29s    |
| 06m09s    |
| 00m06s    |
| 00m00s    |
+-----------+
```

I want to convert this format: 00m00s into hh:mm:ss.

For example:

```
22m59s should be 00:22:59
5h58m38s should be 05:58:38
```

How can i do this in MySQL?

I tried using the query:

```
UPDATE table SET duration = sec_to_time(duration);
```

This did not work and I am lost. All comments and answers are greatly appreciate, thank you so much!

Comment: `sec_to_time` expects the argument to be a number of seconds. You need to parse those `Duration` strings and convert them to seconds. Multiply hours by 3600, multiply minutes by 60, and add them to the seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would i go about doing this? Can you give an example?

Comment: With lots of `LOCATE` and SUBSTR` calls. It's annoyingly complicated in SQL, and it's dinner time so I'm not going to spend the 15 minutes it will take to come up with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SEC_TO_TIME` use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). As you have three formats, you need to call it three times. As it returns `NULL` when it fails (and it fails up to two times as only one of the three formats will match), use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to get the first non-`NULL` value which is the time you're looking for.

```
UPDATE table 
   SET duration = COALESCE(
                     STR_TO_DATE(duration, '...'), 
                     STR_TO_DATE(duration, '...'), 
                     STR_TO_DATE(duration, '...')
                  )
;
```

With the help of the manual you should be able to figure out the format strings I've left open with `'...'`.